# Processing large XML string in avro field - MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

We have an hdfs file that has multiple avro records. We have a field in the avro record that can contain large XML strings (up to 10GB).

Input e.g.

```
{
  id: 1,
  content: "<data><item>...</item><item>...</item>...</data>"
},
{
  id: 2,
  content: "<data><item>...</item><item>...</item>...</data>"
}
```

From what I understand with MapReduce, we can create our own input split to partition the data. If the file was just plain xml, we could probably use something like 
[XmlInputFormat](https://mahout.apache.org/docs/0.13.0/api/docs/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.html) to split on a particular xml tag. In this case, it's inside an avro field. It seems like one mapper will take on a whole 10GB string, which would be really slow.

Is there any way to chop up this data efficiently on the xml item tag? The desired output would be to have an avro record for each item.

Output e.g.

```
{
  data_id: 1,
  item_data: "<item>...</item>"
},
{
  data_id: 1,
  item_data: "<item>...</item>"
},
{
  data_id: 2,
  item_data: "<item>...</item>"
},
{
  data_id: 2,
  item_data: "<item>...</item>"
},
...
```